# Colour coding or flag an entry based on imported field information in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have an excel spreadsheet with a list of high profile customers.
I have a list in sharepoint that I need to flag if any of those high profile customers are added to the list.
Is there a way to link the data in the spreadsheet (like a vlookup or something) to then flag, highlight, colour code or any way of differentiating them from the other customers when looking at the list?
I'm not very advanced with editing sharepoint but I've just downloaded sharepoint designer if it can be done in there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around, (because SharePoint can't do it)
link Excel to the SharePoint list data

You can then do the linking/lookup in Excel

Easier... *but does require basic MS-Access knowledge*..
is doing it with MS-Access (linked to SharePoint data **and** the Excel file)
and making a very basic database JOIN between the two

It is worth investing time in learning MS-Access,
I often do "SharePoint" (*but also regular Excel*) work
in a fraction of the time it takes "Excel copy/pasters" to work with data

MS-Access is one of the most powerful tools in the Microsoft toolset

Huge advantage when linking Access over Excell  to SharePoint data
is that **MS-Access can also write to SharePoint, where MS-Excel can only read**.

Comment: Thanks for your response  Danny, that makes sense. I'll have to spend some time to learn access and then give it a go but it sounds like it'll be worth while.